# Does setText() method always set value to a string?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Does the method setText() always set to a string? If we want to set a Double value to the text field, hows it done?

Comment: .setText( varDouble.toString() );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setText()` only accepts a `String`. In order to insert a `double`, you can just concatenate the double to a string:

```
double someDouble = 2.5;
yourJTextField.setText("" + someDouble);
```

Notice that the double displays as `2.5`. To format the double, see [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.util.Locale,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)).

---

**Edit, 5 years later**

I agree with the other answers that it is cleaner to use [`Double.toString(someDouble)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)) to do the conversion.

Answer (score 4):

You transform the Double to a string first:

```
textField.setText(myDouble.toString());
```

At the risk of contradicting the other answers here, a primitive double should, IMHO, be transformed to a String using `Double.toString(d)` or `String.valueOf(d)`, which expresses the intent more clearly (and is more efficient) than concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an actual Double object then you can use:

```
textField.setText( doubleValue.toString() );
```

Or, if you have a double primitive you can use:

```
textField.setText( doubleValue + "" );
```